# Android phone cellular hotspot with security camera

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I have a spare Samsung note 8 that I am using as a cellular hotspot for a security camera. I leave this at the marina on my boat's tower to keep an eye on the weather as it takes a pic every minute. I am having two issues, the first one is that when the camera is using wifi to hotspot it doesn't upload pic to ftp server.. the second issue is that I cannot connect to the camera by using the public ip and port 80 to access the camera dashboard.

When the camera is connected to the router's wifi then I can access the dashboard and the camera can upload to ftp. Is this due to phone firewall or I need some sort of port forwarding or how can I get this to work?

Comment: Phones usually can not be accessed via cellular network because of CGNAT used by mobile network provider. If the cellular uses IPV4 this today simply a technical necessity as most MNOs don't have enough IPv4 addresses to provide every phone one.

Comment: maybe you are interested in [opposite](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242370)